# Calling instance method from class method: Possible or no?

Tags: objective-c, static-methods, class-method

In a previous post I explained that I was converting an old 'C' program into Objective-C, and learned the difference between messaging (old version) static methods and class methods.

However, how can I now get a class method to call an instance method (assuming it's even possible)? Here's the original (static) function:

```
static int newSplitB(int b, int hi, int lo, int found)
{
 int hlp;

 if(hi - lo <= 1)
   return 0;

  bIs(lo + (hi - lo + 1) / 2); // calls function bIs();
  return 1;
}
```

and the exact same code 'translated' into Obj-C:

```
+(int)newSplitB :(int)b :(int)hi :(int)lo :(int)found
{
int hlp;

if((hi - lo) <= 1)
    return 0;

[TablesClass bIs:(lo+(hi-lo+1)/2)]; // gives compile error
return 1;
}
```

The 'bIs()' function -- snipped for brevity -- is sitting in a separate source file in my 'Tables' class. Unfortunately, attempting to build the program gives me a 'TablesClass' undeclared (first use in this function) error, even though the class has been alloc/inited earlier in the same implementation file.

I've searched the net for hours for a solution, but to no avail. If what I'm trying to do isn't possible, how can I modify the last method to do what I'm after? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Is `bIs` a C function or a `TablesClass` method?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your are importing the `TablesClass.h` file otherwise the current class won't know of its existence and is the common issue when dealing with this error.

Comment: Hi raidfive. Yup. I've re-checked this a thousand times to make sure this wasn't the problem. In fact I went overkill and gave every one of the seven different classes all the headers (whether they needed 'em or not) just to make sure. Made no difference, unfortunately. Thanks for your willingness to help me out here :-)

Comment: No problem, it was worth a shot :) Usually the first thing I check. Interested to see what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1):

You said you "alloc/inited" the TableClass earlier in the same implementation file but it seems like you are using it like a static method. You don't have to alloc/init an instance of a class when you want to use its static methods. Also, if you alloc/init at instance of the TableClass, then that means you stored it somewhere that the static method newSplitB could access.

Comment: Hi kailoon. I should've clarified when I said I'd alloc/inited everything. The original code is split into seven distinct classes (or groups of code), and the 'Tables' group contains a **mix** of instance and class methods. Thought I'd better mention I'd inited them all just in case someone thought I might have overlooked to do it (feasible... and in which case I wouldn't have had access to the instance methods either of course). Appreciate your helping me out here :-)

Answer (score 1):

it is possible, and it is not possible, depending on how you view it:

to call an instance method, you need an instance of an object. you can send this message from a class method, if you have an object.

without an instance of the class, you can't call the instance method anywhere.

you may call class methods from anywhere (assuming it's visible in the translation).

if `bIS` is just a c function, then there is no *need* for it to be an instance method. in fact, you could leave it as a c function.

(maybe an extended example would help us understand why this must be an instance method)

Comment: Hi Justin. Good point about 'C' functions. There's no reason why every line of this 18yo code **must** be converted to Obj-C other than a natural tendency to do it -- which opens up lots of other possibilities like using NSMutableArray's simpler array handling methods etc.. But the problem will still be how to declare any (unchanged) static 'C' methods like my first snippet and get it to compile. Code is 1,300 lines so I focused on the known problem rather than attempt an extended example and not know where to stop. Appreciate your help here :-) Give me another week on this...